# How to quick switch between Jack the drone's support abilities in Gears 5?

Tags: pc, keyboard, gears-5

A tooltip popped up but I couldn't read it in time.
Going through the game menus doesn't show any control for the same? All the websites online talk about controllers - I want the mouse/kb button for the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, You have to press Shift and then a mini menu pops up that you can press 2 or 4 on to quick switch.
Gears 5 conditions you not to press Shift key for anything so didn't think of pressing it.